# Image slider: back an image

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I followed a tutorial on how to create image slider with jquery but he didn't show how to add next image and previous image, so I'm trying to do that my self. The next image part is working but I can't get previous image to work. https://jsfiddle.net/vmab7xk6/10/

```
    //slider
        var sliderWidth = 960;
        var sliderSpeed = 1000;
        var sliderPause = 5000;
        var sliderCurrent = 1;
        var sliderInterval;

        var $sliderLocation = $(".slider");
        var $sliderContainer = $sliderLocation.find(".slides");
        var $sliderSlides = $sliderContainer.find(".slide");

    // img slider
        function startSlider() {
            sliderInterval = setInterval(function() {
                $sliderContainer.animate({'margin-left': '-='+sliderWidth}, sliderSpeed, function() {
                    sliderCurrent++;
                    if(sliderCurrent === $sliderSlides.length) {
                        sliderCurrent = 1;
                        $sliderContainer.css("margin-left", 0);
                    }
                });
            }, sliderPause);
        }

        function pauseSlider() {
            clearInterval(sliderInterval);
        }

        function backSlider() {
            $sliderContainer.animate({"margin-left": "+="+sliderWidth}, sliderSpeed, function() {
                sliderCurrent--;
                if(sliderCurrent === $sliderSlides.length) {
                    sliderCurrent = $sliderSlides.length - 1;
                    $sliderContainer.css("margin-left", "-1920");
                }

            });
        }

        function nextSlider() {
            $sliderContainer.animate({"margin-left": "-="+sliderWidth}, sliderSpeed, function() {
                sliderCurrent++;
                if(sliderCurrent === $sliderSlides.length) {
                        sliderCurrent = 1;
                        $sliderContainer.css("margin-left", 0);
                }
            });
        }

        $("#sliderControllsLeft").on("click", function() {
            backSlider();
            console.log("left");
        });

        $("#sliderControllsPause").on("click", function() {
            pauseSlider();
            console.log("pause");
        });

        $("#sliderControllsStart").on("click", function() {
            startSlider();
            console.log("start");
        });

        $("#sliderControllsRight").on("click", function() {
            nextSlider();
            console.log("right");
        });

        startSlider();

<section class="slider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li class="slide"><img src="img/slider_01.jpg"></li>
                <li class="slide"><img src="img/slider_02.jpg"></li>
                <li class="slide"><img src="img/slider_03.jpg"></li>
                <li class="slide"><img src="img/slider_01.jpg"></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="sliderControlls">
                <li id="sliderControllsLeft"><</li>
                <li id="sliderControllsPause">=</li>
                <li id="sliderControllsStart">+</li>
                <li id="sliderControllsRight">></li>
            </ul>
        </section>

section.slider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 100px 0;
}

section.slider .slides {
    display: block;
    width: 6000px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

section.slider .slide {
    width: 960px;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul.sliderControlls {
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul.sliderControlls li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few syntax errors. See updated fiddle: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vmab7xk6/8/)

You needed to declare the jQuery shorthand `$` before using it. I added a wrapper function that does that. On your JS, (at least on the fiddle), you did not include your slider variables - I added those.

Comment: Sorry about that, forgot to update the fiddle link, I fixed it. You're link isn't working its a 404 error.